# Spring 4 Security Tiles 3 Custom Success Handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tiles-3

I'm having a rough time figuring out how to redirect to a page defined in tiles configuration.

Using Spring Security 4 with annotations and Tiles 3.

The `CustomSuccessHandler` below works but it doesn't resolve the `targetUrl` to the page defined in tiles configuration.

```
@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();


@Override
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

    if (response.isCommitted()) {
        System.out.println("Can't redirect");
        return;
    }
    test();
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
static void test() {

}

protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
    String url="";

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =  authentication.getAuthorities();

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
        roles.add(a.getAuthority());
    }

    if (isAdmin(roles)) {
        url = "/admin";
    } else if (isUser(roles)) {
        url = "/user";
    } else {
        url="accessDenied";
    }

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my problem was self-inflicted, as usual. I had neglected to define "admin"or "user" above, in my views.xml (tiles configuration) file. Once I configured the pages in views.xml, it started working as expected. Thanks!